# AMP-FORM: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, json, nginx, amp

Ответ сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx
    Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 18:42:26 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Connection: close
    Expires: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 18:42:26 GMT
    Cache-Control: max-age=86400
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Surrogate-Control: max-age=3600
    Vary: Cookie,fastly-ssl
    Surrogate-Key: node
    Content-Language: en
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 09:16:34 +0000
    X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://site.ru
    AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://site.ru
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
    access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token
```

На странице:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
```

заголовки добавлены через виртуальный хост:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://site.ru";
add_header AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin "https://site.ru";
add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin";
add_header access-control-allow-headers "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token";
```

Форма:

```
<form target="_top" action-xhr="/" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate=""></form>
```

При отправке формы:

```
Failed to parse response JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Страница содержит простую форму с несколькими полями. Из-за того что на странице несколько `cdn.ampproject.org` приходится добавлять заголовки `AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin` с именем домена, но при этом выходит ошибка `Failed to parse response JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` форма отправляется, но страница не перезагружается.

Подскажите что сделал не так?

Comment: где же сам json то?

Comment: нету. Json не используется, но из-за того что в форме вместо атрибута action указан action-xhr, включается парсер json (я так думаю).